# How does Physical Based Shading work with multiple light sources?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, pbr

I have implemented a PBR shader in my game engine that works with a single light source.  Everything is good and made sense at a higher level about what each algorithm does. Now I am working on adding multiple light sources and I do not understand how to calculate the specular and diffuse BSDFs where each light source hits the object differently. Here is a sample pseudocode of my GLSL shader:

```
float metallic = calculateFromMetallicMapAndFactor();
float roughness = calculateFromRoughnessMapAndFactor();
vec4 baseColor = calculateFromBaseColorTextureAndFactor();

const float dielectricSpecular = 0.04;
vec3 diffuseColor = mix(baseColor.rgb * (1 - dielectricSpecular), vec3(0.0), metallic);
vec3 f0 = mix(vec3(dielectricSpecular), baseColor.rgb, metallic);
float alpha = roughness * roughness;

vec3 F = schlickFresnel(f0, VdotH);
float G = schlickSpecularGeometricAttenuation(alpha, NdotV, NdotL);
float D = ggxNormalDistribution(alpha, NdotH);

vec3 diffuseBRDF = (vec3(1.0) - F) * (1 / PI) * diffuseColor;
vec3 specularBRDF = F * D * G / (4 * NdotL * NdotV);

vec3 color = lightColor * NdotL * (diffuseBRDF + specularBRDF);

outColor = toSRGB(vec4(color, baseColor.a));
```

This is based on one light position where `NdotL` is cosine of angle between vertex normal and light direction.

Now I am adding more lights, how will that work. Do I need to basically calculate BRDF properties per light source and then just add the color outputs?

```
vec3 combinedColors = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
foreach light source {
  calculateDotProducts();

  vec3 F = schlickFresnel(f0, VdotH);
  float G = schlickSpecularGeometricAttenuation(alpha, NdotV, NdotL);
  float D = ggxNormalDistribution(alpha, NdotH);

  vec3 diffuseBRDF = (vec3(1.0) - F) * (1 / PI) * diffuseColor;
  vec3 specularBRDF = F * D * G / (4 * NdotL * NdotV);

  vec3 color = lightColor * NdotL * (diffuseBRDF + specularBRDF);

  combinedColors += color;
}

outColor = toSRGB(vec4(combinedColors, baseColor.a));
```

Sample Model using the above formula:

[image: Shader Result]

Real Life Teapot with two phone flashlights pointed at it:

[image: Real Life Teapot]

Comment: Do you observe any unwanted results when you sum the colours from each light as you've shown above?

Comment: To be honest, I do not fully know. It looks like it is working. I typically try to follow a resource when learning these things and there was nothing about this anywhere; so, I wrote it myself. Though, I still have my doubts on whether it is working correctly or not.

Comment: Let's attack it from a different angle then. Let's take a real-life object, and shine a flashlight on it, and record the light we observe bouncing back. Now let's leave the first light on, and shine a second flashlight on it. Do the photons from the second light somehow block or modulate the photons from the first light? (Keeping in mind these are flashlights, not lasers where all the photons are in-phase) Or do we observe just photons bounced off the object from the first light plus (+) photons bounced of the object from the second light?

Comment: So, I took a cast iron teapot (its metallic and has roughness from the looks of it) and pointed to phone flashlights at it and I see two "reflection points"; so, the lights do not block each other (maybe except for dispersion of reflection surfaces are blending but nothing more). I think I my light calculations are good enough for the time being. Thank you for guiding me through it! I never though of testing things in real world to see if my simulated results are accurate. (edited post a new picture of real world test).